# List items along with button for each item Android

Tags: android

I have an array list containing few elements. What i want to do is to display the items on the screen along with a button for each item. The button is an install button that would install the selected app. What is the ideal way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about ideal but you can

1) Create a new layout representing your list item. It will, probably be a horizontal `LinearLayout` with a `TextView` and a `Button`

2) Subclass your own, say,  `MyAdapter` from, say, `ArrayAdapter`

3) Override `getView()` of your Adapter class where you will have

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View v = convertView;
      if(v == null) {
          v = View.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item_layout, null);
      }
      TextView txtName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.mytext);
      Button   btnAction = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
      // then you do whatever you need with your text and button
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex..Could u please point me to a detailed code that does the same..?